# Codeigniter : How to fetch different column data from foreign table using foreign key id?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, codeigniter

I was able to successfully fetch data in the following table.  However, in the 'Class Teacher' column, I want the teacher name instead of the teacher id (foreign key)
[image]

This is the database table

[image]

Here is how I fetch data in the class view

```
if( !empty($class_data) ) {
                                    foreach ($class_data AS $row) {
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->class_id; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->grade; ?> </td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row->capacity; ?></td>

                                            <td> <?php echo $row->teacher_id; ?></td>
```

my controller

```
function index()
{

    $teacher_data= $this->Tableview_model->fetch_teacher_data();
    $class_data = $this->Tableview_model->fetch_class_data();

    $data["teacher_data"]  =  $teacher_data;
    $data["class_data"]  =  $class_data;


    $this->load->view('classes',$data);
}

function add_class()
{
    $class_data = array( 
        'class_id' => '',
        'grade' => $this->input->post('grade'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('class_name'),
        'capacity' => $this->input->post('capacity'),
        'teacher_id' => $this->input->post('class_teacher'),

    );


    $insert = $this->Model_Action->insertTable('class',$class_data);

    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));


}
```

teacher database table

> CREATE TABLE `teacher` (  `teacher_id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,  `t_f_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,  `t_last_name`
>   varchar(250) NOT NULL,  `DOB` date NOT NULL,  `t_email` varchar(250)
>   NOT NULL,  `t_address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,  `t_tel` varchar(150)
>   NOT NULL,  `t_username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,  `t_password`
>   varchar(500) NOT NULL,  `qualifications` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, 
>   `t_date_of_join` date NOT NULL,  `t_date_of_leaving` date NOT NULL, 
>   `t_current_status` int(1) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`teacher_id`) )
>   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Model fetch_class_data function

```
  function fetch_class_data()
  {
    $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from('class');

            $query=$this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            return $query->result();


        }else{
            return false;
        }


  }
```

Comment: Can you share `teachers` table structure and model function code?

Comment: I did update the question with teachers table and model function code

Comment: Answered below. You need to use a join to get teacher name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` between `class` and `teacher` table. Please change your model code to:

```
$this->db->select('c.*, t.t_f_name, t.t_last_name')
         ->from('class c')
         ->join('teacher t', 'c.teacher_id = t.teacher_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Use `t_f_name` and `t_last_name` in your view as full name by concatenating them

So, replace

```
<td><?php echo $row->teacher_id; ?></td>
```

**with**

```
<td><?php echo $row->t_f_name . " " . $row->t_last_name; ?></td>
```